# Examples of a commutative ring without an identity in which a maximal ideal is not a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

In a commutative ring with an identity, every maximal ideal is a prime ideal.
However, if a commutative ring does not have an identity, I'm not sure this is true.
I would like to know the counterexamples, if any.
The more examples, the better.

**EDIT**
I would like to know the counterexamples other than $2\mathbb{Z}$.
The more examples, the better.

**EDIT**
I also would like to know the counterexamples that are not given in [the Arturo Magidin's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169188/a-maximal-ideal-is-always-a-prime-ideal) if any, namely an example of a non-prime maximal ideal which does not contain $R^2$.

Comment: Let $R$ be the ring and $I$ be such a maximal ideal. Write $S=R/I$. I claim that if $S$ is finite, then $S$ has a trivial multiplication table, i.e. $ab=0$ for all $a,b\in S$. There exists an element $x\in S\setminus\{0\}$ such that multiplication by $x$ is not injective; then, $xS=0$ the only proper ideal. However, the set $N=\{x\in S:xS=0\}$ is an ideal, whence $N=S$.

Comment: @YACP I'm asking more examples. What's wrong with this question?

Comment: @MakotoKato As YACP points out, the other question has a general theorem, not only the $2\mathbb Z$ example.

Comment: @YACP I added new edit.

Comment: @MakotoKato What do you mean by *Arturo's condition*? The only time he uses the word "condition" explicitly is when he's talking about prime ideals, and I really doubt you are asking us to ignore those. Are you talking about something else? Please just spell it out in the post. Thanks!

Comment: @rschwieb I added an explanation.

Answer (score 19):

You won't find any examples of maximal, non-prime ideals other than those given in [Arturo Magidin's lovely answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/169251/10968).  I won't even assume commutativity.  And I freely admit that this is basically the same argument as in Arturo's answer!

**Claim:** *If $R$ is a [rng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-ring) with a maximal ideal $M$ that is not [prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_noncommutative_rings), then $R^2 \subseteq M$.*

**Proof:** Let $M$ be such an ideal, and suppose that $A,B$ are ideals of $R$ not contained in $M$ such that $AB \subseteq M$. By maximality of $M$ we have $M + A = R = M + B$.  It follows that $$\begin{align*}
R^2 &= (M+A)(M+B) \\
&= M^2 + AM + MB + AB \\
&\subseteq M,
\end{align*}$$ since $M^2,AM,MB,AB \subseteq M$.  QED

Combining this with Arturo's theorem, we have:

**Corollary:** Let $R$ be a rng with maximal ideal $M$. Then $M$ is not prime if and only if $R^2 \subseteq M$.

Comment: yes, very clear

Comment: @MakotoKato why not accept this answer?

Answer (score 17):

Take $R=2\mathbb{Z}$, the ring of even integers. The ideal $4\mathbb{Z}\subset R$ is maximal (the only larger ideal is $R$ itself), but not prime, as $2\cdot 2\in 4\mathbb{Z}$, but $2\not\in 4\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of parodies on the $2\Bbb Z$ example.

You can look at $R=2\Bbb Z[x]$: the ideal $(2x,4)=I$ is maximal, and again $2^2\in I$ and $2\notin I$.

Here's another: let $M$ be any $2\Bbb Z$ module. You could, for example, let $M=2\Bbb Z$, or any number of copies of $2\Bbb Z$. Look at the following ring of matrices and ideal:

$$
R=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{bmatrix}\mid a\in 2\Bbb Z, b\in M\right\}
$$

$$
I=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{bmatrix}\mid a\in 4\Bbb Z, b\in M\right\}
$$

Again, $\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}^2$ shows $I$ isn't prime.

Finally to get a noncommutative example, try

$$
R=\begin{bmatrix}2\Bbb Z&2\Bbb Z\\0&2\Bbb Z\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
I=\begin{bmatrix}2\Bbb Z&2\Bbb Z\\0&4\Bbb Z\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
J=\begin{bmatrix}4\Bbb Z&2\Bbb Z\\0&2\Bbb Z\end{bmatrix}
$$

$I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, $J\nsubseteq I$, but $J^2\subseteq I$, so $I$ isn't prime.

Answer (score 4):

I will prove the following fact.
Let $R$ be a commutative ring without an identity.
Let $M$ be a non-prime maximal ideal.
Then $R/M$ has a prime order.

**Proof**
Let $S = R/M$.
Since $R^2 \subset M$ by the Manny Reyes' answer, $S^2 = 0$.
Hence every subgroup of the additive group $S$ is an ideal of $S$.
Since $S$ has no non-trivial ideals, the order of $S$ must be a prime number.
**QED**

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be an abelian group of prime order.
We define multiplication on $R$ by $ab = 0$ for all $a, b \in R$.
Then $0$ is a maximal ideal but not a prime ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The following example is a generalization of the example $2\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $p$ be a prime number.
Let $R = p\mathbb{Z}$.
Then $R^2 = p^2\mathbb{Z}$ is a maximal ideal but not a prime ideal of $R$.