# Yes/No : Is the set of all function vanishing at both $0$ and $1$ is maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the  set of all function  vanishing at both   $0$ and  $1$ is  maximal ideal ? Yes/no

My attempt : i know  that  it will not prime  ideal  take $f(x) = x-1 $ and $ g(x) = x$. where $f, g \in C[0,1]$

But here im confused  about maximal ideal.?

I thinks  yes

Comment: A maximal ideal of what ring? Which functions exactly (domain, codomain...)?

Comment: If your ring is $C[0,1]$, then your attempt already answers the question. It's not prime, hence not maximal.

Comment: @QiZhu   domain is $ [0,1]$

Comment: @QiZhu  every prime ideal need not be maximal !!!!

Comment: Read my whole comment and answer all of it. Yes, prime ideals need not be maximal - however maximal ideals are prime.

Comment: @QiZhu $C[0,1]$  is a infinite ring  so  every prime ideal need not be maximal.....but if Ring is finite  then we can say every prime is  maxim al

Comment: Please read my comments precisely before answering... Prime implying maximality and maximality implying prime are two entirely different things.

Comment: @QiZhu ya  i have read ur comment   but im not getting  what  exactly  u want to say  pliz elaborate more.....or u can write  ur answer in answer box

Comment: Then please next time ask questions instead of immediately bashing what other people are writing. I have tried to explain my comment as an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suppose the ring in question is $C[0,1]$. Let the proposed ideal be $I$. Now, $I$ is not prime as you have noted (since $fg \in I$ but $f \not \in I, g \not \in I$), but then surely it cannot be maximal.

(There seems to be some confusion about maximality and primality. One very important fact is that every maximal ideal is prime. You can read this up in every elementary abstract algebra book. So if $I$ were maximal, then it has to be prime. But that isn't the case as you have shown.)

Comment: "Every maximal ideal is prime." True in rings with unity (and rings with $R^2=R$). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169188/a-maximal-ideal-is-always-a-prime-ideal/169251#169251).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the set of all functions vanishing at $0$. It is an ideal. How does it compare to the one you're asking the question about.

Comment: u  mean  at  $0$  both  $f$ and $g$  is not vanish

Comment: @jasmine Nope; forget about any particular $f$ and $g$ as the ones you defined. An ideal $I$ is maximal if there is no bigger ideal other than the whole ring. You're asking the question if $I$, the set of functions vanishing at $0$ and $1$, is a maximal ideal or not. I propose to consider $J$ the set of functions vanishing at $0$ (but not necessarily at $1$). Then $I\subsetneq J\neq C[0,1]$, and $J$ is an ideal.

Comment: ya i got its @Scientifica   thanks u..

Comment: @jasmine: But note that to establish $I\subsetneq J$ you should *exhibit* a function that is in $J$ but in in $I$. In this case, $x\mapsto x^2$ would do it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks u sir